# Sync SQLite3 database with iCloud

Tags: ios, sqlite, synchronization, icloud

This question ha been asked a number of times before, but I have been unable to find a full answer. I need to store data in my app using an sqlite3 database and core data is not an option. I want to synchronise the data across devices using iCloud, and the best approach to this seems to be to send SQL transaction logs to iCloud and use them to keep device up to date. The process I've come up with so far is as follows:

- All database altering queries (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) once executed are stored in a transactions array, each element of which contains the sql query and the timestamp it was carried out
- The database contains a table for logging the point in the transactions array that the app last got to (including the filename of the transactions file stored on iCloud)
- Transactions array saved to device-unique file on iCloud
- When syncing:

  1. Get array of transactions files from iCloud
  2. Create empty array of transactions to be committed
  3. For each file:

     - Check database for last position got to in transaction file
     - If none, start from beginning of file
     - Add each transaction from that point to the array of transactions to be committed
     - Update database with new last position of transaction file so the synced transactions are not repeated
  4. Sort the array of transactions to be committed by transaction timestamp
  5. Execute the commands in the array of transactions to be committed

I am confident that I can get this working in terms of pulling the data down to each device and carrying out the commands to update each local copy. The only problem I envisage is if two devices insert a record to the same table while both offline and then sync. For example:

1. Device 1 and device 2 both have synchronised copies of the database, with four records each in the table "table1"
2. Device 1 inserts value "foo" to table "table1" with PK 5
3. Device 2 inserts value "bar" to table "table1" with PK 5
4. Device 1 downloads transaction log for device 2 and inserts value "bar" to ID 6
5. Device 2 downloads transaction log for device 1 and inserts value "foo" to ID 6

We now have a situation where the primary keys for these records are inverted on each device, which will break links to tables which rely on the primary key for linking.

I'm still trying to research a solution to this but in the meantime if anybody has an suggestions I would be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been thinking about this all day and I think I've come up with a solution. I'm posting it here to see if anyone has any comments, and I'll be having a go at implementing it tomorrow.

My idea is to do away with an auto-increment, integer primary key and replace it with a string-based key. The key will be generated from the device's UUID and the time stamp. This means the key is device specific and row unique. So, to rephrase the INSERT example from above using this method (using simplified key strings for ease of reading):

1. Device 1 and device 2 both have synchronised copies of the database, with four records each in the table "table1"
2. Device 1 inserts value "foo" to table "table1" with PK "abc123"
3. Device 2 inserts value "bar" to table "table1" with PK "def456"
4. Device 1 downloads transaction log for device 2 and inserts value "bar" to ID "def456"
5. Device 2 downloads transaction log for device 1 and inserts value "foo" to ID "abc123"

This works because the devices know that the transactions will result in he insertion of rows which are keyed using device specific values. There is therefore no danger of duplicate values in the keys column after the insert operation.

Any thoughts on this approach would be welcome!

UPDATE
I'm marking this as the correct answer as it worked. Here's how I modified my existing database (and app) to allow synchronisation across devices. Fortunately this is not a production app yet so the significant changes to the database which were required have not caused a problem.

1. Change all database tables to use a TEXT type column as their primary key
2. Add a "last index" table to the database which is keyed with the table name and has one other column to show the index number of the last row added to that table
3. Added a method to the app which generates a device- and row-unique TEXT key by retrieving the last inserted index for the table and incrementing it by one, and then adding to this the device's UUID.
4. When inserting any rows, the method described in (3) is invoked to obtain an appropriate key for inserting the record into the database
5. All database-modifying functions result in the SQL query being added to a transaction log, each entry of which is also date and time stamped and saved to a local file using the device's UUID as its filename
6. The device's local transaction log is then pushed up to iCloud
7. Syncing involves the following:

   - Download all of the transaction logs from iCloud
   - Ignoring the device's own transaction log, go through the list of SQL commands in each log and add them to an array of commands, starting from the index number finished at for that log on the last sync
   - Store the index number finished at for the log in the database so the same commands are not re-executed on the next sync
   - Sort the array of all SQL commands from all logs by date
   - Execute the commands in order

With regard to implementation of this process, I have got as far as step 5. None of the iCloud-specific stuff has been implemented yet. However, I have tested the process by manually copying the transaction logs between devices running copies of the app and I can confirm that the process works. The TEXT primary key containing the device's UUID ensures that no clashes occur. All devices can insert each other's data and the keys will always be unique.

The downside of this is that the database will be larger (because the keys are longer than an integer), and queries probably take longer as there is lots of string comparison involved. However, the database I am using is relatively small and there are just a few queries per user interaction so I do not anticipate a problem here.

I hope this is useful to other who come along with the same question :)